# Hibernate/JPA - Delete table with @OneToMany relationship (one parent- 0 or more child of the same type) violates foreign key constraint

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have a problem when trying to delete a table with @OneToMany relationship to table created
from the same java class using

```
Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery("DELETE FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName());
q.executeUpdate();
```

Here's the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE p_data_group
(
  data_group_id bigint NOT NULL,
  description character varying(350),
  description_eng character varying(350),
  multiplicity_max integer,
  multiplicity_min integer,
  name character varying(35),
  name_db character varying(30),
  name_eng character varying(35),
  name_xml character varying(35),
  path character varying(1024),
  "position" integer,
  is_root boolean,
  parent_group_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT p_data_group_pkey PRIMARY KEY (data_group_id ),
  CONSTRAINT fk_data_group_parent_group_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_group_id)
      REFERENCES p_data_group (data_group_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE p_data_group
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And here's the part of the class that represents relations:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_group_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@XmlTransient
public DataGroup getParentDataGroup() {
    return parentDataGroup;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_group_id")
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_data_group_parent_group_id")
@Index(name = "idx_data_group_parent_group_id")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@XmlElementWrapper
public List<DataGroup> getChildDataGroups() {
    return childDataGroups;
}
```

Now when trying to delete to root table all others should be deleted as well according to CascadeStyle.ALL annotation :

> > PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "cpdm01" violates foreign key constraint "fk_cpdm01_kodpkd_cpdm01_id" on table
> >     "cpdm01_kodpkd"   Detail: Key (cpdm01_id)=(100) is still referenced
> >     from table "cpdm01_kodpkd".

Am I right here?

Comment: The error message is talking about another FK, in another table. And delete queries don't care about your cascades. They're translated to a SQL query, and this SQL query is executed, that's all.

Comment: It is more the reverse situation: you are letting something being deleted cascaded (translated: it will happen whether you like it or not) while there is a possibility that this record is referenced from another table. I wouldn't cascade delete something when that situation exists, you need more precision there and only delete when it is possible to delete.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Error log shows

```
DETAIL: Key (cpdm01_id)=(100) is still referenced from table "cpdm01_kodpkd".
```

There is still a record referencing to cpdm01_id 100. You might delete record in cpdm01_kodpkd with cpdm01_id = 100 before , but there might be others as well. 
You have to delete all records in cpdm01_kodpkd referencing to cpdm01_id 100 in main_order. 
If not, the database protects you from doing harm to your data.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Is there any solution(method) to use instead  executeUpdate() that will do it automatically?

Comment: Can you add some relation details about this fk_cpdm01_kodpkd_cpdm01_id key you can automatically delete all child records and sub-child records of parent by adding cascade = CascadeType.ALL to all child of parents.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @slavo could you please give more mapping details ? like where you apply this "fk_cpdm01_kodpkd_cpdm01_id" foreign key constraint in your code

Comment: the table is created dynamically, based on the template above